# Excel VBA- Remove Date in dynamic filename

Tags: vba, excel

I am amateur to VBA.

My objective is to zip the folder with multiple files which i have managed to achieve. But I need to format the file names.

Some files in the folder might contain date either as prefix or suffix of filename (example: `ddmmyyyyexpense.xlsx` or `expenseddmmyyyy.txt`).

I would like to remove the date from the file name.

**Note:**  I could have any file type

> .xls
>      .xlsx
>      .csv
>      .txt

I tried using wildcards appending to one of the strings and 
`VBtextcompare` but it didn't work.

Comment: And so far you have tried?

Comment: I tried only in zipping which worked. I m trying vbtextcompare which is not fruitful. I do not know what to be used or  any inbuilt function that can help me

Comment: @brettdj VBtextcompare did not work. I tried even using wildcards appending to one of the  strings. Still it does not work.Kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I like a RegExp I will :)

This code looks for an eight digit number, tests if this is a valid date, and if so removes it.

If you have more than one possible date, or if the 8 digits are surrounded by other numbers it will need refining.

The code below feeds three sample strings to the cleaning function, it strips the date from the first and third, leaves the second as is.

```
Sub TestDate()
Debug.Print CleanStr("01142012expense.xlsx")
Debug.Print CleanStr("421142012expense.xlsx")
Debug.Print CleanStr("expense16042015.xlsx")
End Sub
```

*code*

```
Function CleanStr(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})"
    If .test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        If IsDate(objRegMC(0).submatches(0) & "/" & objRegMC(0).submatches(1) & "/" & objRegMC(0).submatches(2)) Then
            CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
        Else
            CleanStr = strIn
        End If
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I am sure this is gonna work. I will try now. Anyway what if the code has string like 17 Apr 2015? I would like to handle that scenario well. By the time you come up with answer, atleast i will try to replicate this.. :)

Comment: .No words. Amazing. My hours of thought process you did in no time. wonders me. Thank you and much grateful. Genius !!

Comment: I didn't test it, but it probably works. I only wonder why you split it in 3 parts. Since the entire date should be removed, you might as well define your pattern as "\d{8}", which will make your If statement a lot easier as well. Unless you want to be certain that it is a date, but in that case the regex would be a lot complexer.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens which is why i split it into three parts to use a simple ISDATE to test for a valid date (rather than a complex regexp).

Comment: @brettdj somehow I overlooked that part of the If statement. My appologies.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens no probs, it wasn't overly obvious. cheers

Comment: @brettdj what would be the best way to remove the string(April, Apr, Month). Just give me hint, I can try to expedite.

Comment: @brettdj Hope I have asked you a stupid question. Now i  found the same can be achieved through regex. Implementing..